# javascript function undefined in rails project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails project. I need to call a tracking function named “trackEvent()” on scroll of the home page.

```
<section class="features_section card_section border-b-c" onwheel="trackEvent('HomePage Scroll','Scroll','Features Section');"></section>
```

This trackEvent() function is being used to track events through out the website (in all the pages), so it is written in the common javascript file which has been included in the asset_pipeline of rails.

The thing is, once the home page html loads (**the javascript hasn’t been loaded yet**), and I start scrolling, the on wheel event is triggered, but the trackEvent function comes to be **undefined**.

This happens in other cases as well, the scroll case is just one example.

One workaround we have been using is checking if jQuery has loaded (since jQuery is also included in the asset_pipeline) by embedding a script like the following in all the html views:

```
function checkJquery() {
  if (window.jQuery) {
      trackEvent('HomePage Scroll','Scroll','Features Section’);
      // or some other task
  } else {
      window.setTimeout(checkJquery_outstanding, 1000);
  }
}
checkJquery();
```

This script ensures that the function is called only after it has loaded.

But it has become kind of tedious, including these setTimeouts in all the views. I just want to know if there is a better way of organising such javascript code in a rails project.

I hope I was clear with the question.

Comment: sorry about that, wrote it in the notes and copied from there. corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for Rails, specifically, but the general answer is that if you want that function not to be attached until your JavaScript is loaded (which is reasonable), don't attach it until your JavaScript is loaded. This is one of the many reasons not to use the old-fashioned `onxyz` attributes for event hookup.

Instead, hook up the handler *in* your JavaScript code:

```
$(".features_section").on("wheel", trackEvent);
```

(You may need to make taht selector more specific.)

Then, it won't be hooked up before it's available. Just put that in a `script` element that's after the HTML it refers to (just before the closing `</body>` tag is good), or if you don't control where the script tags go, use jQuery's `ready` callback.

Comment: I am putting forth another case with a similar issue: Suppose I want to trigger this `trackEvent()` when a certain div loads (on page load) out of a possible two divs. The decision logic is in ruby. Now, if I hook up the handler in a script just after the div, the js file containing the function definition wouldn't have loaded yet, so it would still be undefined. And my sole intention of the question was to avoid `ready` callbacks in each and every view.

Comment: @NiharPanigrahi: You *don't* use a script tag after the div. Just hook it up in your JavaScript code that's defining the handler. There's no reason to separate them. If you have two different divs, each with its own handler, differentiate them via CSS selector and write the code that hooks both of them up -- since one of them won't exist, it won't get hooked up. (One of the many joys of jQuery being set based is that `$("some-selector").on("wheel", ...);` **doesn't** cause an error if the selector didn't match anything, like it would with element-based APIs like the DOM or PrototypeJS.)